# Why the throughput of publish/subscribe systems is stable?

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe, faye, pushpin

I try to measure the performance of different publish/subscribe systems, (rabbitMQ, apache kafka, pushpin,faye). In the first cycle, I try to measure the performance for **1000 requests** with **concurrency = 200**. In the second cycle, I measure the performance for **10000 requests** with **concurrency = 200**.
However, I see that the throughput for the 2 measures do not change but it is stable in every pub/sub system.

For example, the throughput at rabbitMQ is:

- 1000-requests,200-concurrency => throughput = 256.33
- 10000-requests,200-concurrency => throughput = 261.24

Can you explain me why this is happens?

Comment: Did you try on another machine with higher IO rates? Different disks? More memory? Clustered environment vs standalone servers? There's too many variables here to plainly answer this, but a benchmark on your local machine shouldn't be conclusive of what works the best at scale

Comment: Yes, also I runned the tests in GCP console but the results was almost and I different hardware variables. Also, if I increased the number of concurrent users and the results are also the same. I expected different throughput in second cycle. Can you explain some reasons for these results or can you suggest me an article? Thanks :)